# Unity Activating Text UI From Two Different Scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having some sort of logic error. Basically, I'm trying to have HUD text display when a player gets close to either an NPC or an object. I have two separate scripts currently tied to the NPC and the object. For testing purposes, the code is exactly the same between the two:

```
void CheckDist()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(playerBody.position, npcBody.position) < detectDist)
        {
            
            controlText.text = "Press 'e' to talk.";
            Debug.Log("In Range: " + Vector3.Distance(playerBody.position, npcBody.position));
            controlText.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        }
        else { controlText.gameObject.SetActive(false); }
    }
```

Basically, it checks the distance of the player to the respective object and either displays the "Press 'e' to talk" or "Press 'space' to pickup". This runs in FixedUpdate(). For some reason, the Text UI element will only activate either for the NPC or the object. I can get it to activate for the NPC only if I disable the object in the editor. The text itself for either one will updated oddly enough. Is there something about SetActive that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you trying to set the same controlText in the two scripts?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I was hoping to reuse the same UI Text element.

Comment: if you are reusing the same UI Text element, doesn't that mean only one instance of the object can appear? It means that u cant "snatch over" the same element with 2 different scripts

Comment: The problem with your code is that: Script one detects that u are close enough to the object, so it sets the Text to enabled. But meanwhile, script two detects that you are not close enough, so it sets the Text to disabled. That is why the text only works when you are using one script at a time. An easy fix will be to use one text for one gameObject/script.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! I see you are using the [tag:unityscript] tag, please note that this is (as explained in the tag info) a deprecated scripting language made by Unity, and not an encompassing term for all scripts in Unity. Your question is about C# (and I have thus removed it for you, no need for you to do anything :) ). Please only use this tag if you're working on legacy code using the actual language UnityScript. This keeps the question and tags in line with each other :)

Comment: Thanks @IllegalRazer. That makes sense. It displays as expected for one script which I think is where my confusion was. I was expecting a situation where either both would work or neither would. I think it might be better to rework this system and tie it to the player instead of each object. That way should allow me to reuse the UI Text I think. :)

Comment: Thanks @Remy! I'll try to pay more attention to the tags in the future.